# How do you write a Fish function that kills a server on a specified port?

Tags: unix, fish

I am porting my zsh setup to fish. I'm struggling with arguments in fish, though.

```
function kill_server
     lsof -i TCP:$argv | awk '/LISTEN/{print $argv[1]}' | xargs kill -9
     if $argv !== dev 2>null
       echo "Port" $argv "found and killed."
     end
end
```

I've also tried using switch statements, but am not sure how to check for a regex(?) of port numbers.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what that script is supposed to do. Is the idea that the function receives just one argument, which is the port number?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the goal.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want

```
function kill_server --argument port
     for pid in (lsof -i TCP:$port | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}')
         echo -n "Found server for port $port with pid $pid: "
         kill -9 $pid; and echo "killed."; or echo "could not kill."
     end
end
```

The `$2` in the awk body is not a fish variable, it belongs to awk.

Comment: That works! Can you explain some more about the fish-specific syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything there in particular that's troubling you? The `and` and `or` commands correspond to bash's `&&` and `||` conditional  list operators. The --argument option is [documented in the `function` command docs](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function)